# How to Google transliterate words in a textarea automatically through JavaScript (without manually pressing the spacebar or Enter key)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transliteration

I am using the below HTML code published as an example at https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
    <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to fill the content of the textarea and output the transliteration through JavaScript.
I tried focusing on the textarea and triggering "Enter" keypress/keydown/keyup. But none of them works. I have to manually press the Enter key or spacebar for the transliteration to work.

Please find below the code that I tried in the console.

```
$("#transliterateTextarea").val("hello"); # This sets the textarea content as "hello"
$(document).on("mouseup", "body", function(e) {
    $("#transliterateTextarea").show().focus();
    var oldval=$("#transliterateTextarea").val();
    $("#transliterateTextarea").focus().val(oldval);
    var e1 = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
    $('#transliterateTextarea').trigger(e1);
});
```

Now, when I click anywhere on the body of the HTML, the textarea is focused and the cursor is shown at the end of the word "hello". But the Enter key press is not simulated and the transliteration is not performed.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"The Google Transliterate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011."_

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know if there is any workaround that can simulate the manual keypress

Comment: Hi, Have you got it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the onChange event for the textarea, using jQuery https://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$("#transliterateTextarea").change(function() {

  // call your translit function

});
```